# Trying to get the XML element attributes using JIBX

Tags: java, xml, maven, xsd, jibx

I have an XML where some of the elements have attributes. Following is the example;

```
<RATES>
 <DATE>09/30/2014</DATE>
 <TIME>06:35:00</TIME>
 <STATE CODE="AK">
    <PRODUCT/>
    <PRODUCT/>
 </STATE>
 <STATE CODE="AL">
    <PRODUCT/>
    <PRODUCT/>
 </STATE>
</RATES>
```

I have defined the XML Schema Definition as follows:

```
<xsd:element name="RATES" type="RATES_REF" />

<xsd:complexType name="RATES_REF">
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="DATE" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
        <xsd:element name="TIME" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
        <xsd:element name="STATE" type ="STATE_REF" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="100">
            <xsd:complexType> 
                <xsd:attribute name="CODE" type="xsd:string" use="required"></xsd:attribute>
            </xsd:complexType>
        </xsd:element>
    </xsd:sequence> 
</xsd:complexType>
```

***Please ignore the STATE_REF detail as I feel it is irrelevant to this discussion.***

Now I am using JIBX to generate the mapping Java objects. I am using Maven and have used a JIBX plugin to generate the Java objects. The generated Java objects are as follows:

```
public class RATESREF
{
  private String DATE;
  private String TIME;
  private List<STATEREF> STATEList = new ArrayList<STATEREF>();
  //Ignore Getters/Setters
}

public class STATEREF
{
  private List<PRODUCTREF> PRODUCTList = new ArrayList<PRODUCTREF>();
  //Ignore Getters/Setters
}
```

My question to you all is why was there no variables created for the State attribute named Code?

Thanks
Raj

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working in the following manner:

```
<xsd:element name="RATES" type="RATES_REF" />

<xsd:complexType name="RATES_REF">
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="DATE" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
        <xsd:element name="TIME" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
        <xsd:element name="STATE" type ="STATE_REF" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    </xsd:sequence> 
</xsd:complexType>

<xsd:complexType name="STATE_REF">
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="PRODUCT" type="PRODUCT_REF" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
    </xsd:sequence>
    <xsd:attribute type="xsd:string" name="CODE"/>
</xsd:complexType>
```